# Why my association isn't working properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :team
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :players
end
```

schema:
    ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150125183356) do

```
create_table "players", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "player_name"
t.float    "price"
t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
t.integer  "team_id"
end

create_table "teams", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "team_name"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

end
```

this is the scenario

When I go to rails console and type

```
t= Team.new
t.team_name='ss'
t.save
p=Player.new
p.player_name='sdeas'
p.price=33.0
p.save
```

then when I type p.team=t
it works fine.

but when I type t.players
it shows me `#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>`

I want to find players for that team.
I am sure I am doing a mistake in somewhere as I am new to rails.

Comment: Does it work after you type `t.reload`?

Comment: yes, t.reload is returning the values of t

Comment: Now try `t.players`..

Comment: tried, same as before

Comment: What's the output of `rake db:migrate:status` ?

Comment: up     20150125180645  Create teams
   up     20150125180800  Create players
   up     20150125183147  Add team id to players
   up     20150125183356  Remove player id from team

Comment: Shouldn't you do something like t.players << 'wtv'

Comment: Now it works when I am trying Team.first.players

Answer (score 0):

Everything in your models and schema look fine. I'll bet you're just experiencing console issues.

First, try this:

```
t = Team.create(team_name: 'ss')
p = t.players.new(player_name: 'sdeas', price: 33.0)
p.save
```

Then `t.players` *should* return an array of players.

Second, are you saving the player after you do `p.team = t`? If you're not, then the DB query for `t.players` won't return any players.

Comment: yes, I saved after that. 
     
 
Now it works when I am trying Team.first.players,but what was the problem before?

Comment: The problem before was that you didn't fill the team_id field when you created your player record.  evanbikes' solution (t.players.new(player_name: 'seas', price: 33.0)) does that for you by creating the new player on the team (t.players.new).